# What data type to use for opening hours in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, time, intervals

I want to keep track of opening hours of various shops, but I can't figure out what is the best way to store that.

An intuitive solution would be to have starting and ending time for each day. But that means two attributes per day, which doesn't look nice.

Another approach would be to have a starting time and a `day to second` interval for each day. But still, that means two attributes.

What is the most commonly and easiest way to represent this? I'm working with oracle.

Comment: Why do you think having two attributes that record different information doesn't look nice? Wouldn't that be the most obvious way of doing it?

Comment: @jpw is right, but you can also use something like BigInt to store the beginning and the end in high and low bytes like in old sweet times :) Btw, what's the DB?

Comment: @jim Those were the days eh?

Comment: as an option - minutes from 00:00 for the beginning and the end.

Comment: Alright, alright. I just hoped there would be a way to easily store this information and then check if a given time is in the interval. How it will have to be a longer condition to check ^^

Comment: Opening hours is by definition two numbers. So your objection against 'two attributes' makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes total sense to have two Column One for Open DateTime  and One for Close Datetime. Since Once a shop is open it will have to be closed someday/sometime.

**My Suggestion** 
I would Create a separate table for shop Opening/Closing Times. Since everytime A shop is opened it will have a close time value as well so you wont have any unwanted nulls in you second column. to me it makes total sense to have a separate table altogether for shop opening closing times.

Answer (score 3):

The lowest granularity you need is probably minutes (actually, probably 15 minute intervals, but call it minutes).

Possibly you also want to consider day of the week.

If you use a table such as:

```
create table day_of_week_opening_hours(
  id                            integer primary key,
  day_of_week                   integer not null,
  store_id                      integer not null,
  opening_minutes_past_midnight integer default 0 not null,
  closing_minutes_past_midnight integer default (24*60) not null)
```

Pop a unique constraint on store_id and day_of_week, and for a given store and day of the week you can find the opening time with:

```
the_date + (opening_minutes_past_midnight * interval '1 minute')
```

or ...

```
the_date + (opening_minutes_past_midnight / (24*60))
```

Shops that open 24 hours a day could be represented with a special code instead of opening times, in a separate table instead of with special opening and closing times, or maybe you could just leave the opening/closing times null.

```
create table day_of_week_24_hour_opening(
  id                            integer primary key,
  day_of_week                   integer not null,
  store_id                      integer not null)
```

Think about shops that do not open at all on a given day as well, and how to represent that.

Probably you could do with a date-based override also, to indicate different (or no) opening hours on certain dates (Xmas, etc).

Quite an interesting problem, this.

Answer (score 2):

I done something similar once and I used NUMBERs:

```
START_DATE  END_DATE
0700        1800
0915        1745
0600        2300
1115        2215
```

It was easy to use with the plain SQL i.e. with BETWEEN clause.

What if a store has a break?

Answer (score 0):

Since oracle does not have a date only or time only datatype, you are going to need to use the date datatype which is both date and time.  The intuitive solution you mentioned looks pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements have two data points: an opening time and a closing time.  There are different ways of representing the information, but you will need two attributes.

I understand why you think having two attributes will lead to "a longer condition to check" whether "a given time is in the interval".  But Oracle provides many ways to manipulate its
DATE datatype.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079).

One useful mask is `'SSSSS'`, which is the number of seconds past midnight.  So, if you hold opening and closing times as seconds you can check the interval like this:

```
select * from shop
where sysdate between trunc(sysdate) + (opening_time_sssss/86400) 
              and trunc(sysdate) + (closing_time_sssss/86400)
```

I'm not saying it's elegant but it is effective.

---

Actually, it would be possible to store the opening hours in a single attribute: by representing them as a bit mask in a RAW column.  That would be harder to understand and even less elegant to check.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but Timespan would be good